# How can I screenshot the whole desktop?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, jquery

Is it possible to screenshot the whole desktop of users visiting my website?

I am using the PHP function `imagegrabscreen()` but it's only working on localhost. Is this done on the server or can I do this with WebRTC without a chrome extension?

Comment: you can have the use press printscreen then, grab the copied image from the clipboard. otherwise no.

Comment: @dandavis can i printscreen another website with window.open

Comment: No you can't, and that's a good thing! Image the privacy issues!

Comment: If you could, it would be a major security flaw on the part of browser developers: it doesn't take a lot to imagine a user having their password safe open elsewhere on the screen, or a sensitive email. What are you actually trying to do this for?

Comment: @Matthew i just want to know Is that possible to screenshot user information

Comment: you can capture whatever you want, just press print screen and the webapp can do the rest.

Comment: You can create a keylogger to capture any data typed onto your web page. It's ethically questionable to do so, but it is possible. Otherwise, if you want the image, you need to preset the user with on-screen instructions for what you want them to do. And only if they participate willingly will you receive the image from them.

Comment: @daddygames i want to create a button and when user click on this button the web server automatically screenshot whole desktop.

Comment: @YusufHR I understand. However, without a browser extension installed on the client browser, you will not be able to accomplish what you want to do. You can ask the user to save a screenshot and then upload it.

Comment: If you had a Node.js server you could screenshot users using the Puppeteer module.

Answer (score 11):

> Is this done on the server

Yes. Of course. PHP is a *server-side* language.

> Is it possible to screenshot the whole desktop of users visiting my website?

Not without asking them to do so.